# Is there an easy way to work out what element is failing the "content wider than screen" test on Google's Mobile-Friendly test

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

I have a website with many complex pages. The pages are responsive and use Bootstrap, but have different types of content in the body. Some of them fail Google's Mobile-Friendly test, with the error "Content wider than screen".

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

On many pages it is not obvious which content is causing the problem. Is there a tool or method so I can easily work out where the problem lies? At the moment I'm having to puzzle it out on each page, which is time-consuming.

Comment: Have you tried the pages in Firefox and Chrome's mobile layout emulator?

Comment: Yes, that just displays the page, it does not tell you what element on the page is causing it to be wider than it should be. (Less there is something I'm missing?

Comment: Set screen narrow enough and usually you can see what element breaks the layout and then pick it up with the Inspector tool

Comment: But if it is a long page and the issue is in the body there there is no way of telling. There are lots of long pages. It's very time consuming going through the code of each one trying to work out what the issue is.